# Doing Tests with Jest in a Node+EJS environment

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, ejs, render

- The EJS tool uses 'render' calls to send HTML to frontend:

  const allMessages = await repository.getAll(user_id);

  return res.status(200).render('messages', {data:allMessages});
- To do integration tests with Jest calls the route:

  await request(server)
  .get(`/messages/${user.uid}`)
  .send()
  .expect(200)
  .expect(async (res) =>
  ... etc ...
- Problem is that Jest behavior prevents the EJS calls (render method) to reply correctly to the test. That line above

  return res.status(200).render('messages',{data:allMessages});

do not reply with code 200 but with code 500 !

- To pass the test that line must be replaced by

  return res.status(200).json(allMessages);`

Only then the Jest test pass with the expected 200 reply code.

Question: How to pass an integration test with Jest and at the same time use the EJS render method to send HTML to the frontend ?

Comment: As Jest is from Facebook, they will prefer the use of React and not EJS...

Comment: My "solution" was to drop EJS and render all the HTML in the front end.

Comment: You should answer your own question if you found the solution, providing its details

Comment: To drop EJS was _not_ a solution. The solution would be to be able tu do Jest tests _with_ EJS.  There is no solution to this question at all. So I drop the subject.